# Need help passing an object inside of a loop

Tags: c#, scope

I need help passing "dependentcombobox" into the for loop.  The error I am getting is "The name "dependentcombobox" does not exist in current context." How do I get it into the for loop?  I would like to keep the scope as narrow as possible.  Thank you! Language is C#.

```
public frmMain() 
{
  InitializeComponent();

  populateDatacombobox(comboboxBlower1Series, comboboxBlower1Model);
  populateDatacombobox(comboboxBlower2Series, comboboxBlower2Model);
  populateDatacombobox(comboboxBlower3Series, comboboxBlower3Model);
}


public void populateDatacombobox(ComboBox independentcombobox, ComboBox dependentCombobox) 
{
  DataSet blowerData = Global.blowerData;

  DataTable blowerTable = blowerData.Tables["blower"];

  var comboBoxValues =
      (from records in blowerTable.AsEnumerable() where records.Field <
          string > ("SERIES") == independentcombobox.SelectedItem.ToString()
          select records.Field < string > ("MODEL"));

  foreach(var comboBoxValue in comboBoxValues) {
    dependentcombobox.Add(comboBoxValue);
  };

}
```

Comment: is the `;` after the foreach end curly brace a typo?

Answer (score 2):

C# is [case sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity) language. So `dependentcombobox` is not equal to `dependentCombobox`. Your parameter name is `dependentCombobox` while you are writing `dependentcombobox` while using in loop. and also you don't need to put terminator `;` at the end of body of loop.

Corrected chunk:

```
foreach (var comboBoxValue in comboBoxValues)
{
  dependentCombobox.Add(comboBoxValue);
}
```

Comment: This was the problem.